# How do I access user in Django Async view?

Tags: python-3.x, django, async-await

I'm trying to access user but getting an error when the view is `async`.

Code:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse


async def archive(request):
    user = request.user
    return JsonResponse({'msg': 'success'})
```

error message:

```sh
django.myproject.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

What I tried:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


async def archive(request):
    # user = sync_to_async(request.user)
    # user = sync_to_async(request.user)()
    # user = await sync_to_async(request.user)
    user = await sync_to_async(request.user)()
    return JsonResponse({'msg': 'success'})
```

Still getting the same error.

I want to access the user to check he/she has permission to archive a file.

EDIT:
I eventually figured out that I had to move it into a temporary method and run that as `sync_to_async`. I did this below:

```py
def _check_user(request):
    user = request.user
    ''' Logic here '''
    return

async def archive(request):
    await sync_to_async(_check_user, thread_sensitive=True)(request=request)
    ''' Logic here '''
```

And this seems to work, But not sure if this is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async

@sync_to_async
def archive(request):
    user = request.user
    return JsonResponse({'msg': 'success'})
```

I don't know if it's really async, I'm trying to fix this problem too.

---

I've found something: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/django-q/

If the first option not work, see this link.

Comment: thank you the first option worked out nicely for what I needed to do

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to access `user` from an async view is:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from django.contrib import auth

async def myview(request):
    user = await sync_to_async(auth.get_user)(request)
```

Django 5.0 will add an [`.auser` method](https://github.com/django/django/commit/e846c5e7246a0ffbe5dcf07a2b6c7c2a47537eb3#diff-6b551f383fcc71f808a17d213b0f925ce9655ce58f18cb7ca3a6052eb3b72b8b) to the `request` object.